# Is 1 Joule the work done to lift ~100g through a distance of 1m?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, displacement

I am seeing many videos saying that 1 Joule is the work done to lift ~100g through a distance of 1m (like this one https://youtu.be/BYpZSdSEk4A?t=348).
The idea is that 100g has a gravitational force downward of 1 Newton. So lifting it means applying 1 Newton over 1m, and therefore is 1 Joule.

But if I apply 1 Newton upward, and gravitational force is 1 Newton downward, the object shouldn't move.

So I believe you need to apply a force greater that 1 Newton in order to lift it. 
Or am I missing something?

Would it be more accurate to say that 1 Joule is the work done by gravity to make fall 100g by 1 meter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A few questions about the concept of work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74154/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to start lifting the object you will need to apply a force larger than its weight so that it will have an upwards acceleration.  This force does not have to be much large than the weight, it could be larger by an arbitrarily small amount, it just depends on how much time you want to spend lifting.  The lifting force also doesn't have to be larger than the weight for very long.  Once again, if you are prepared to lift the thing very slowly you could have the lifting force larger than the weight for an arbitrarily short time.

Once you have lifted the object 1 m (or actually before) you need to decelerate it so that its speed is zero at the end.  This means you'll need to use a lifting force slightly smaller than the object's weight.  This slightly smaller force at the top end exactly compensates for the slightly larger force you had to use to start it moving at the bottom.

Comment: I see, I didn't thought of the deceleration phase. This is exactly the explanation I was looking for. This makes sense now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your example of lifting an object, if the upward external force is exactly the same as the weight in magnitude, then the object is still in perfect equilibrium. And since the initial velocity of it was zero, its velocity would still remain zero because equilibrium means no acceleration. So, there would be no movement. So, in order to actually lift the object, you do need to provide an upward force which is at least slightly greater than the weight of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Joule is the work done by a force of 1N (1 Newton) when moving the object by 1m (1 meter). It is one of [the SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), that is: it is defined in terms of the basic units of kilogram, meter and second.

- Given the free fall acceleration of $9.8m/s^2\approx 10m/s^2$ the gravity force acting on an object of mass 100g=0.1kg is about 1N, which means that (in terms of the magnitude of the force) the quoted statement is *approximately correct*.
- If the net force acting on an object is zero, it will remain at rest of move with a constant speed (assuming that we are in the inertial reference frame). Thus, if we apply the force that balances the gravitational force, we can move the stone with constant speed. Both the applied force and the gravity force do work of approximately 1J, but these works are of different sign.